# Unable to import module 'app': Error at Function.Module._resolveFilename in AWS using Claudiajs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, aws-lambda, claudiajs

i ususally get this error with "claudia update".
i am using node 6.10, npm 5.6.0
if i zip manually and then upload to lambda it works.
what can be issue?

*Below error in aws console log*:

```
Unable to import module 'app': Error at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15) at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25) at Module.require (module.js:497:17) at require (internal/module.js:20:19) at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/request/lib/helpers.js:3:25) at Module._compile (module.js:570:32) at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10) at Module.load (module.js:487:32) at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12) at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

Question asked at: [Gitter](https://gitter.im/claudiajs/claudia?at=5a586866290a1f45617c4dbc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do npm pack and see what gets copied
it’s likely that your package.json or .npmignore exclude that file
or that some dependency is marked as dev instead of production
check out [Claudia-packaging](https://claudiajs.com/tutorials/packaging.html) for more info on how to control and troubleshoot packaging

Answer by: [Gojko](https://github.com/gojko) at [Gitter](https://gitter.im/claudiajs/claudia?at=5a5896b4290a1f45617d3ae8) that solves the issue.